# SQL Update to flip sign of a value?

Tags: sql, sql-update

Someone entered a ton of numeric data into a table with the sign backwards.

Is there a clean way to flip the sign in the numeric column with a SQL statement?

Comment: Whatever you do, be sure to do a "BEGIN TRANSACTION" so you can quickly roll it back if you screw it up. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
update my_table
  set amount = -amount
  where <whatever>
```

Answer (score 4):

`UPDATE [table] SET [column]=([column]*(-1))`

You can add a `WHERE` clause as needed to limit which rows you are flipping signs on.

Answer (score 2):

It should be straightforward.

```
update table set column = -column;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET amount = -amount
WHERE amount = ABS(amount)
```

By including the amount = ABS(amount) clause you prevent unnecessary log activity and index maintenance.  It's always a good idea to only update the rows that actually need it.

Comment: this will only make all amounts positive and not swap the positives to negatives.

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for the check.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me in SQL Server

```
 update my_table
 set amount = ~amount
 where <condition>
```